# Display a menu with distinct categories using Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I would like to show a menu that displays only the distinct categories.

Imagine to have the following structure:

_folder1

1. com1.html
2. com2.html
3. com3.html

Now, let me focus only about three files.

For every file contained in the _folder1 you have the following YAML MATTER

TITLE: 1File 
 
type: y 
project: 1

TITLE: 2File 
type: y
project: 1

TITLE: 3File 
type: y
project: 2

Now, I'd like to show the following list:

Projects

- 1
- 2

and I don't want to have a double 1.

What is the best practice to reach it in Jekyll ?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but you need some **very** ugly string manipulation hacks to achieve it.

As far as I know, there's no proper way in Liquid to create arrays by yourself.
So 90% of the following solution consists of abusing strings in order to create arrays.

```
<!-- Step 1: create an array with all projects (with duplicates) -->

{% for page in site.pages %}
    {% if page.project %}
        {% capture tmp %}{{ tmp }}#{{ page.project }}{% endcapture %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% assign allprojects = tmp | remove_first: '#' | split: '#' | sort %}


<!-- Step 2: create an array of unique projects (without duplicates) -->

{% for project in allprojects %}
    {% unless tmp2 contains project %}
        {% capture tmp2 %}{{ tmp2 }}#{{ project | strip }}{% endcapture %}
    {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}

{% assign uniqueprojects = tmp2 | remove_first: '#' | split: '#' | sort %}


<!-- Step 3: display unique projects -->

<h1>Projects:</h1>
<ul>
{% for project in uniqueprojects %}
    <li>{{project}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

---

In the end, step 3 will generate the following HTML...exactly as requested:

```
<h1>Projects:</h1>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
```